# System.Reflection performance

Tags: c#, sqlite, reflection

I have a database manager for inserting or adding into an internal SQLite database as well as for reading.

For read back, I use a generic method such as this

```
 public List<T> GetListOfObjects<T>(string id) where T:IIdentity, new()
    {
        lock (dbLock)
        {
            using (var sqlCon = new SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
            {
                sqlCon.Execute(Constants.DBClauseSyncOff);
                sqlCon.BeginTransaction();
                string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE id=\"{1}\"", GetName(typeof(T).ToString()), id);
                var data = sqlCon.Query<T>(sql);
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
```

Nothing amazing, but all of my read methods amount to roughly 130 lines of code.

My setters though are different - almost 1500 lines covering a whole pile of classes. What I would like to do is rationalise the insert/update methods using system reflection and to not worry about the class being inserted to, but allow reflection to do it for me.

From what I've read, this is entirely possible and I should therefore be able to compact the code to something akin to this

```
public void InsertOrUpdateClass<T>(List<T> obj) : where T:IIdentity, new()
{
     foreach(var o in obj)
         InsertOrUpdateClass(o);
}

public void InsertOrUpdateClass<T>(T o) : where T:IIdentity, new()
{
     lock (dbLock)
        {
            using (var sqlcon = new SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
            {
                sqlcon.Execute(Constants.DBClauseSyncOff);
                sqlcon.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    // use reflection to construct the SQLite command line, insert
                    // into a string and pass into the query
                   if (sqlcon.Execute(SQLquery) == 0)
                        sqlcon.Insert(o, typeof(T));
                    sqlcon.Commit(); 
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error in InsertOrUpdateClass : {0}", ex.Message);
                    sqlcon.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
```

However, from what I have read, using reflection to do this would give a performance hit of about x5 over the more standard single method per class for insert or update. Most of the examples I've seen suggest that as I'm not using anything nasty (like Activator.Create...), my method should be as fast as "standard" code

The classes (as they are for a database) have different lengths and have added data parameters of [Ignore] and [PrimaryKey]. I've not found anything over if reflection would get confused over these two.

Any advice would be appreciate on this.

Comment: There could be many reasons for the slow performance 1. SQLite could be slow when you have large amount of data. 2. You are opening a new connection and committing the changes for every db update. This could be optimized.

Comment: I've found keeping a connection open for the length of operation of an application to be a bad idea. As sqlite is just a file, if the app crashes, the file stays open and/or becomes corrupted. An open and close on each call while costly greatly reduces the chances of that. I find SQLite to be fast for what I need, but the question is would system.reflection cause a massive slowdown if I implement that instead of the 1500+ lines of code that all do effectively the same thing

Comment: No... The above code doesn't seem to cause any performance bottleneck except what I mentioned before. This code should be sufficiently good in performance, if the update rate is not high. (Previously I have used SQLite with high update rate with large amount of data and SQLite caused considerable performance degradation.)

Comment: You already gave your own answer: it could be slower, but you won't know until you measure it. That being said, why do you want to reinvent the wheel? Look into some libraries like PetaPoco or Dapper which already do that in probably the fastest way possible

Comment: Kenneth - thanks for the heads up on those two. I have to ensure that the code though will work on mobile platforms too so I need to tread carefully and just use what MS/Mono have given me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very basic/naive approach using expression trees. You would definitely need to do some work on this, depending on the complexity of your objects, but it should be a good starting point:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<Object, String>> queryBuilders =
   new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, string>>();

public String GetInsertQuery(Object entity)
{
   var type = entity.GetType();
   if (!queryBuilders.ContainsKey(type))
   {
      var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Object), "entity");
      var typedObject = Expression.Variable(type, "obj");
      var stringBuilder = Expression.Variable(typeof (StringBuilder), "sb");

      var appendString = typeof (StringBuilder).GetMethod("Append", new[] {typeof (String)});
      var objectToString = typeof(Object).GetMethod("ToString");

      var code = new List<Expression>();
      code.Add(Expression.Assign(typedObject, Expression.Convert(param, type)));
      code.Add(Expression.Assign(stringBuilder, Expression.New(typeof (StringBuilder))));

      code.Add(Expression.Call(stringBuilder, appendString, Expression.Constant(string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} (", type.Name))));

      var properties = type.GetProperties();

      for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length - 1; i++)
      {
         code.Add(Expression.Call(stringBuilder, appendString, Expression.Constant(properties[i].Name)));
         code.Add(Expression.Call(stringBuilder, appendString, Expression.Constant(", ")));
      }

      code.Add(Expression.Call(stringBuilder, appendString, Expression.Constant(properties[properties.Length - 1].Name)));

      code.Add(Expression.Call(stringBuilder, appendString, Expression.Constant(") VALUES (")));

      for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length - 1; i++)
      {
         code.Add(Expression.Call(stringBuilder, appendString, Expression.Constant("'")));
         code.Add(Expression.Call(stringBuilder, appendString, Expression.Call(Expression.Property(typedObject, properties[i]), objectToString)));
         code.Add(Expression.Call(stringBuilder, appendString, Expression.Constant("', ")));
      }

      code.Add(Expression.Call(stringBuilder, appendString, Expression.Constant("'")));
      code.Add(Expression.Call(stringBuilder, appendString, Expression.Call(Expression.Property(typedObject, properties[properties.Length - 1]), objectToString)));
      code.Add(Expression.Call(stringBuilder, appendString, Expression.Constant("', ")));

      code.Add(Expression.Call(stringBuilder, appendString, Expression.Constant(");")));


      code.Add(Expression.Call(stringBuilder, "ToString", new Type[] { }));

      var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Object, String>>(Expression.Block(new[] { typedObject, stringBuilder }, code), param);
      queryBuilders[type] = expression.Compile();
   }

   return queryBuilders[type](entity);
}
```

Although this uses reflection as well, the main difference is that reflection is used once and further calls for each object type use compiled code, so there's no significant performance hit. The main drawback is obviously complexity - the simple approach, far from being fool-proof and universal took quite some lines of code - you definitely need to consider if the benefits of reducing the code base (and also potentially improving maintainability) is worth the cost (which is maintainability as well - but instead of thousands of methods, you have one which is quite complex).

Comment: Thanks - this is a similar approach to what I took in the end. The maintainability question is always important but it has to be weighed up against the bug count. If I change the class, I have to also change the query, this could be trivial but when the database guy is in Queensland and I'm in the UK, he could make changes to 7 classes to test something and so the chances of missing something this end increases. At least this way the *data* going in will always be right.